# Keras image dataset from directories: select classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm a loading an image dataset as follows:

```py
LABELS = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
train_ds = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(ASL_PATH, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2, subset='training',class_names=LABELS)
```

The following are the specs of the dataset:

```
(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
 TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))
```

And it contains 29 classes. I do not need all of them and I want to keep only a subset of them. For instance, say that I want to keep only the classes:

```py
desired_classes = [0, 1, 2]
```

How to perform this operation? I think I need to use `train_ds.filter` but I was not able to figure out the exact syntax.

I've tried filtering like so:

```py
def filter_classes(_, label):
    return tf.reduce_any(tf.equal(label, desired_classes))
```

```py
train_ds = train_ds.filter(filter_classes)
```

But as soon as I try to "read" the content of the dataset, I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_2_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Incompatible shapes: [3] vs. [32]
     [[{{node Equal}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext] name:
```